# examples for p-adic representations

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Could anyone recommend me some literature or articles were I can read about the construction of irreducible representation of finite groups (like the symmetric group, alternating group or semidirect products of groups,...) over the p-adic integers? Or maybe even give some ideas how to start. Thank you

Comment: The theory of representations of finite groups is the same over $\mathbb{C}$ or over $\mathbb{Q}_p$. If you don't know the theory over $\mathbb{C}$, then try to look at : Serre, 'Representations of finite group'.

Comment: I know the theory over $\mathbb{C}$ an the article of I.Reiner about the irreducible representations over $\mathbb{Z}$ of the cyclic group of prime order. I never worked with $p$-adic integers before. Why sould it be the same as over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @user10676: Dear user, Since $\mathbb Q_p$ is not algebraically closed, there are subtleties over $\mathbb Q_p$ that do not occur over $\mathbb C$, because of the distinction between irreducible and absolutely irreducible representations, and the possible occurence of Schur indices.  Furthermore, I think that the OP is asking about representations over $\mathbb Z_p$, not $\mathbb Q_p$.  Regards,

Comment: Whould it help to work first over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ and then over $\mathbb{Z}_p$? In the end I need those over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: Dear Alex, Yes, it certainly helps first to work over $\mathbb Q_p$.  If you have a finite dim'l rep'n of the finite group $G$ over $\mathbb Q_p$, then you can always choose a basis so that it is defined over $\mathbb Z_p$.  This $\mathbb Z_p$-model will typically not be unique, though --- this will depend on whether or not the reduction mod $p$ of your representation remains irreducible.  Indeed, the key new feature of working over a ring like $\mathbb Z_p$, rather than a field, is that one really has two fields in play: the fraction field $\mathbb Q_p$, and the residue field ...

Comment: ... $\mathbb F_p$, and a big part of the story involves studying the *reduction* of your representation from char. $0$ to char. $p$.  Regards,

Comment: Thank you Matt E! But how to get the irreducible $\mathbb{Q}_pG$-modules than? Do you know an easy example (like $G=C_p$ cyclic goup) or articles? Best regards, Alex