# Connection between $\mathbb{Q}_p[G]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/166072/examples-for-p-adic-representations) there was the comment, that having $\mathbb{Q}_p[G]$ modules, it is possible to construct $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ modules. How is it possible to find out when there is a bijection between simple $\mathbb{Q}_p[G]$ modules and indecomposable  $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ modules? (Maybe without calculation the characters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will almost never be a bijection between simple $\mathbb Q_p[G]$-modules and indecomposable $\mathbb Z_p[G]$-modules.

For one thing, there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of the former, whereas, unless $G$ has a cyclic $p$-Sylow subgroup, there are infinitely many isomorphism classes of the latter.

(One basic point is that $M$ being an indecomposable $\mathbb Z_p[G]$-module
does not imply that $M\otimes_{\mathbb Z_p} \mathbb Q_p$ is simple over $\mathbb Q_p[G]$.)

Even if we restrict attention to indecomposable $\mathbb Z_p[G]$-modules $M$
for which $V:= M\otimes_{\mathbb Z_p} \mathbb Q_p$ is simple (i.e. $G$-invariant $\mathbb Z_p$-lattices in irred. reps. over $\mathbb Q_p$), there won't be such a bijection in general.

As noted in my comment on the question linked in your post, $M$ is determined up to isomorphism by $V$ only in the special case when $M/pM$ is irred. as a $G$-rep'n.

Comment: Hm, thank you. As this method does not work, do you know maybe a theorem which tells if an indecomposable module from a normal subgroup extends to $G$ (over $\mathbb{Z}_p$)? I know such theorems just for $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: @AndyN.: Dear Andy, I don't think I've ever had to think seriously about that kind of a question.  If $M$ is the module over the normal subgroup $N$, and $g \in G$, then obviously one needs $M^g$ (the module $M$ with the $N$-action twisted by conjugation via $g$) to be isomorphic to $M$, for all $g$.  I don't know much more than that of the top of my head.  Actually, suppose you know this for $V: = M[1/p]$ (that the $N$-action extends to a $G$-action).  Then you are asking whether $M$ itself is $G$-invariant.  The first thing is to check whether $M/pM$ admits a $G$-action.  This will be ...

Comment: ... true for its semisimplification, I guess (since that depends only on $V$, which does admit a $G$-action), but the extension classes appearing in $M/pM$ could give some obstruction.   Another way to approach it would be to choose $M' \subset V$ which *is* $G$-invariant, and minimal w.r.t. the property of containing $M$.  (Equivalently, it is the $Z_p[G]$-submodule of $V$ generated by $M$.)  You want to know if $M = M'.$   Equivalently, you want to know if $M/pM \to M'/pM'$ is an isomorphism (in fact, injective or surjective is enough to imply iso.).   Now $M'/pM'$ will be generated over ...

Comment: ... $\mathbb F_p[G]$ by the image of $M/pM$, so you want to know that the image of $M/pM$ is $G$-stable in $M'/pM'$.  So again, this comes back to thinking about the possibility of a $G$-action on $M/pM$.  So that's definitely the place to start ... .  Regards,

Comment: Thank you, I will try this